# mysql SUBSTR() problem

Tags: php, mysql, substr

Nice easy one for this morning.

Ok, here's my little `sql` statement

`SELECT SUBSTR(quote,1,20) FROM b_quotes WHERE id='74'`

This is returning an empty result which is confusing because if I call upon any other part of that record (the customers email address for example) it returns it perfectly. I've tried variations and it always seems to be the SUBSTR part that is failing.

could anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks 
Shane

Comment: Could you show us some sample data from: `SELECT quote, SUBSTR(quote,1,20) FROM b_quotes WHERE id='74'`?

Comment: @a'r Using the code you just posted, I get the entire sting as a result, not what I'd like (the first 20)

Comment: Try `SELECT SUBSTR(quote,1,20) AS q FROM b_quotes WHERE id='74'`

Comment: Does the following work: SELECT SUBSTR(quote,1,LEN(quote)) FROM b_quotes WHERE id='74'  ???

Comment: @xzyfer Thanks, this works perfectly. And to everyone else, thanks also for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SELECT SUBSTR(quote,1,20) AS q FROM b_quotes WHERE id='74'`

Comment: Actually, while a reader passing by might think that there's a need to add a column alias name, this statement is totally equivalent to the one posted in the question, which is already correct. I believe that this works for @shane because of the way he/she is accessing the data returned from database. So the error is probably in the application code and NOT in the SQL statement.

Comment: @Alessandro - That's exactly what's happening. I'm accessing the information in this manner `$value['q']` whilst in a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't indicated which data type is used for the quote column, try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CAST(quote as CHAR),1,20) FROM b_quotes WHERE id='74'
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the datatype of the `quote` column? If it's a CHAR or VARCHAR, what's its length? What code are you using to access the data returned from the database?

Your SQL statement is correct, so if you want to avoid workarounds and just want to know why your query doesn't seem to work (as you asked) you have to research problems in your application code.